# VLC record button not saving subtitles from DVD

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

Very simple question regarding VLC. I researched and found nothing.

I need to "record" a short clip from a DVD while the keeping the subtitles. So I start playing the segment and the subtitles show up fine. Then I stop recording and look at the saved file. The saved filed has not "captured" the subtitles. I need an elegant solution to have the subs be recorded. This should be very simple but for some reason the "record" button does not include the subs even though while recording they are being displayed. In the end, I want to use the captures to make GIFs with subs. I want to use the included subs from the DVD and not have to resort to .srt files.

http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Recording_Video_With_VLC

^ I read this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, subtitles are generally on a separate file, .srt, that are overlaid onto the movie,so that explains why vlc won't record it. If you get the movie and subtitle files you can burn the subs on then cut as you like.

Comment: This is what I thought. Needlessly adds extra steps. Why won't it just record "what I see" when playing? While playing it shows the subs, but the saved file has it omitted.

Comment: You could create a .srt file of your own to play over your video section, does seem like a bit of  a hassle

Comment: http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_6901846_create-srt-file.html

Comment: How about how to create an .srt file straight from the DVD?

Comment: Also I found the limitation on VLC. http://vinitneo.com/2009/07/record-videos-with-vlc-media-player/

Comment: "Recording of subtitle file is possible only if the subtitle file is embedded in the video. Changing the output format is not possible. You have to use another software like total video converter etc. to do that." One of the comments.